# How to implement a table containing objects of multiple types using blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to implement something like a file explorer view using blazor and mudblazor as a component library.

The API I am working with has two endpoints to get data from:

- Endpoint 1: gives me containers i.e. folders, which can contain more elements
- Endpoint 2: Gives me the files

I want to display them both united in a table view similar to the windows file explorer.

My straight forward idea would be to use a common interface or parent class containing all the common properties. But I also do need some of the other not shared properties displayed.

I am currently stuck on how to implement this and and some input on how to tackle this problem would be really helpful.

Comment: TreeView could be the UI element you are looking for. And a tree could be the data structure.

Comment: Define base class, inherit it by folder, file etc classes. If needed use type checking for showing the needed representation of data.

Comment: Use a dictionary of type to component. Then using reflection based on the type render the component with DynamicComponent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an interface that all your classes implement.

```cs
public interface IFSItem
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; }
}
```

To get specific information you need to test and then cast objects to their specific type.

In the code demo below all the types implement `IFSItem` so we can group them into Collections.

```cs
   public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; }
```

And consume them as their native types.

```cs
@if (item is Folder folder)
{
   <li> Folder >> Name: @folder.Name - ReadOnly: @folder.ReadOnly</li>
}
```

Here's the demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@ItemFragment(_items)


@code {
    private RenderFragment<IFSItem> ItemFragment => (fsItem) => (__builder) =>
        {
            @if (fsItem.Items.Count() > 0)
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in fsItem.Items)
                    {
                        @if (item is Folder folder)
                        {
                            <li> Folder >> Name: @folder.Name - ReadOnly: @folder.ReadOnly</li>
                        }
                        @if (item is File file)
                        {
                            <li> File >> Name: @file.Name - Size: @file.Size</li>
                        }
                        @if (item.Items.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            @ItemFragment(item)
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        };

    private IFSItem _items = new FSItem();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _items = this.GetPlaces();
    }


    private IFSItem GetPlaces()
    {
        var d1_f1 = new File { Name = "Nantes", Size = 2000000 };
        var d1_d2_f1 = new File { Name = "Bezier", Size = 210000 };
        var d1_d2 = new Folder { Name = "Midi", Items = new List<IFSItem> { d1_d2_f1 } };
        var d1 = new Folder { Name = "France", Items = new List<IFSItem> { d1_f1, d1_d2 } };
        var d2_f1 = new File { Name = "Manchester", Size = 2500000 };
        var d2_f2 = new File { Name = "Birmingham", Size = 4700000 };
        var d2_d2 = new Folder { Name = "Scotland", ReadOnly = true};
        var d2 = new Folder { Name = "UK", Items = new List<IFSItem> { d2_f1, d2_f2, d2_d2 } };

        return new FSItem { Name = "F", Items = new List<IFSItem> { d1, d2 } };
    }

    public interface IFSItem
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; }
    }

    public record FSItem : IFSItem
    {
        public string Name { get; init; } = "Not Set";
        public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<IFSItem>();
    }

    public record Folder : IFSItem
    {
        public string Name { get; init; } = "Not Set";
        public bool ReadOnly { get; init; }
        public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<IFSItem>();
    }

    public record File : IFSItem
    {
        public string Name { get; init; } = "Not Set";
        public int Size { get; init; }
        public IEnumerable<IFSItem> Items { get; init; } = Enumerable.Empty<IFSItem>();
    }
}
```

And what you get:

[image]